# Vim folding get expanded with new marker

Tags: vim

If I have a block of css or js that is folded in vim, when ever add a new block above it, the block gets unfolded.

Currently, I just have this in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType css,scss setlocal foldmethod=marker
autocmd FileType css,scss setlocal foldmarker={,}
```

[image: Vim-fold issue]

Is there a way to disable this? 
Will `:h fold` and check, but wanted to ask here as well.

Comment: I have the same issue with all languages I use. Heaven't found a fix yet.

Comment: Does it also happen when you run vim with '-u NONE'? Are you running vim? I can see on your powerline that it says nvim.

Comment: Yes, I've tested this in regular vim as well as neovim, say thing. When testing with `-u NONE`, I got the same thing, as soon as I close the block, the fold below expands.

Comment: Just tested this with following vimrc:

    set foldmethod=marker
    set foldmarker={,}
    filetype plugin indent on

and it is indeed doing some weird things with automatically folding and unfolding stuff. You might want to report this to upstream.

Comment: Opened issues [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3300) and [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `vimrc`, straight from the vim wiki: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text

```
" Don't screw up folds when inserting text that might affect them, until
" leaving insert mode. Foldmethod is local to the window. Protect against
" screwing up folding when switching between windows.
autocmd InsertEnter * if !exists('w:last_fdm') | let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * if exists('w:last_fdm') | let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm | unlet w:last_fdm | endif
```